# What say Kantian ethics about capitalism?

Tags: ethics, kant, categorical-imperative

As I did read, it does not look like Kantian ethics favors socialism (especially given it requires slavery by economic imperative), but I would like a more rigorous analysis.

#### Note that

1. Recall that the definition of Socialism (at least in what is the concern of a Economist) is the public ownership of the means of production (Ball et. al).
2. Recall that Anarchism is the view that a society without the state, or government, is both possible and desirable (Crowder, 1998).
3. Anarcho-Socialism is a self-contradicting concept because you cannot have public property without some kind of state.
4. Note that as explained by this [paper](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/70964/1/MPRA_paper_70964.pdf), democratic socialism is politically impossible because it would imply (1) slavery, (2) suppression of the free press. With a similar argument that can be trivially derived by the same economic proofs, is to say that ancho-socialism is politically impossible.

#### Some previous research

https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Immanuel-Kant-believe-that-treating-man-as-a-mean-was-unethical-Does-that-mean-using-man-to-make-goods-and-paying-him-a-wage-is-wrong

https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-were-Kants-views-on-capitalism

###### APA References

Ball, T. and Dagger, . Richard (Invalid Date). socialism. Encyclopedia Britannica. https://www.britannica.com/topic/socialism

Crowder, G.(1998). Anarchism. In The Routledge Encyclopedia of Philosophy. Taylor and Francis. Retrieved 23 Feb. 2022, from https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/anarchism/v-1. doi:10.4324/9780415249126-S003-1

Comment: "especially given it requires slavery by economic imperative" Capitalism even more.

Comment: Socialism was a mere transient state in Marx, where the ideal was that those who produce *personally or as a community* own that what they produce and the means to do so themselves,  not the state. State socialism like we politically know it has never been envisioned as a stable economic and political institution. It was used by autocratic regimes to hold on to power and wealth.

Comment: Related, as it makes clear that Kant had very limited writings on property in relation to politics and that they do not align well with ending private property: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/40368/17209

Comment: Your definition of socialism is flawed. Socialism is about *collective* possession of the means of production. It does not have to be owned by the state. A workers coop is a socialist entity. Your definition of anarchism is also flawed because most prominent anarchists envisioned some form of state (Proudhon's communes are indeed a form of state). It follows that most of the assertions in your question are equally baseless. More research, and less ideology, seems necessary.

Comment: @Felicia Citation needed.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Seriusly?. (1) Marx did no invent Socialism. (2) Marx is a liar (given that he claimed that the state will wither away, but it is a lie because observation 2 of the question), also he did no care about justifications he wanted overthrow the old truth (Karl Marx & Engels, The Comunist Manifesto), thing that would include any reasonable moral conceived before. (3) Marx never let clear the difference between Communist and Socialism is basically another lie of Marx.

Comment: @armand (1) Literally socialism is the public property of the means of production (Call et. al). (2) Lieterally all the anarchism are against the state (Crowder, 1998). Crowder, G.(1998).

Ball, T. and Dagger, . Richard (Invalid Date). socialism. Encyclopedia Britannica. https://www.britannica.com/topic/socialism .Crowder, G.(1998). Anarchism. In The Routledge Encyclopedia of Philosophy. Taylor and Francis. Retrieved 23 Feb. 2022, from rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/anarchism/v-1. doi:10.4324/9780415249126-S003-1

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Seriously? Just look around you. Capitalists are the new cunning and wicked loan slave drivers, calling their world a free world, which makes them even more sickening.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises So Proudhon, Bakounine, Kropotkine are not anarchists ? Yet they all advocated for some form of collective administration, it is to say, a state. A commune is a government. They were against the state as it is now, but not against the concept of state. Reducing anarchism to just being "against the state" is a caricature for lazy people driven by ideology like you and the OP who pretend to critic it without taking the pain of knowing what it's about.

Comment: Just as lazy as many misinterpretations of the term "socialism" (mainly driven ideologically by the Chicago School of economics btw) and the inability to distinguish the economic theory of Marx from his political errands (that, in turn, are more likely due to Engels).

Comment: means of production can be owned socially without being owned by a state. Again, a workers coop owns its factory, yet is not a state by any stretch of the imagination. You are just sticking to the most caricatural definitions of very complex schools of thoughts in order to make them easily dismissible by strawman arguments like OP tries to.

Comment: @armand (1) definition of state "A political organization of such a body of people" (Merrian-Webster diccionary). (2) I am using the correct and historical definitions of that terms, if you don't think so where are your references?. (3) If a "worker coop" is small enough to no get anykind of hierarchy, the it is no different that a private property, if the "worker coop" is big enough to think of it as socially owned, then it will have political hierarchy therefore will become a state.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises: A state is usually thought to be linked to territorial claims **against other states** (not proprietorial). A mere body of people is not a state or every political party would be a state within the state. The ideal in Marx is that we have groups of equals who collectively *and freely* decide over what they produce and own what they produce, which necessitates that they - as a social group - own the means of production. This is close to the Kantian concept of *sui generis* being necessary for actual political freedom. And this theory as such leaves the question of state open.

Comment: The state ownership comes into play as *material condition* since only a state is able to reorganize private property from individual to social ownership, having the actual power to do so. Therefore, it is seen as a necessary transient state - in Marx. Socialism has sadly become identified with what was called "real socialism" (Realer Sozialismus) by the autocratic systems of the political "east" (Soviet Republic, GDR, Cuba, early China, etc.). Thus, this is the common use of the term these days. That does not mean that it is what originally was intended and thought with this term.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Lazy?. Marx is just pure nonsense and evil, the only thing that is clear is their writings are lies, rationalizations from some a priory laws that he supposes, and his desire of dead and destruction, he said himself “There is only one way in which the
murderous death agonies of the old society and the bloody birth
throes of the new society can be shortened, simplified and
concentrated, and that way is revolutionary terror.” in the Neue Rheinische Zeitung of which he was Editor-in-Chief in May 1849. Say me that honest man would say it? No one. He is as philosopher as Ayn Rand

Comment: @ErdelvonMises: It is very honest insofar as he describes how the contemporary economical and political elites (which are closely intertwined) will do anything in their power to prevent the redistribution of property that is necessary to achieve actual freedom for everybody. Therefore, this redistribution is necessary against violent resistance. The outcome is a revolution, the swifter, the better. Marx, much like Kant btw, basically said that you cannot be truly free as long as you have to work *for others*. One may think of that as one may, but the line of thought is coherent.

Comment: (I do not want to say I follow Marx, I just state that his theory is pretty coherent insofar as he states that you cannot have freedom in the sense mentioned without this "revolutionary terror" simply because there will be powerful opposition by those who currently own the capital.)

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking (1) The keyword is **usually**, usually the state is thought connected to a territorial claim. Big enough "worker unions" are states. (2) The state will no whiter away, without state there is no public property, without public property there is no socialism, Marx is lying. (3) The original name of the Communist Manifesto is "The Communist Confesion of Faith" (p. 4 of Kengor, P. (2020). The Devil and Karl Marx: Communism’s Long March of Death, Deception, and Infiltration. TAN Books.)

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking And again Marx DID NO CREATE SOCIALISM, what he says does no matter to define socialism.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises: If Marxian socialism is compatible with Kantian thought and the socialism of real politics is not, the discussion of this difference is important to the question. You cannot discuss one framework in terms of a different one if the concepts behind the terms are different. And you cannot use terms to your liking, this is intellectual dishonesty. If worker unions are states, so is the Democratic Party of the US or the German CDU with their hundreds of thousands of members and hierarchical structure. That does not make any sense. I'll withdraw from this discussion now.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises: as for your very contrieved misconception of a state, Phillip Klocking have a satisfying answer. I'd add that, obviously, a worker coop does not have any of the  regalian missions usually devolved to a state. It shows how few you understand the concepts you use. My references are the anarchist authors I mentioned above, I go to the source. What you call references is just a cargo cult attempt at the esthetics of academic debate. If you want to appear academic maybe avoid formulations like "evil" or "liar"...

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking (1) Marxian thought is self contradicting in who respect to his economical tought as show by Eugen von Böhm-Bawerk in his book Karl Marx and the Close of His System, more than 100 years ago. (2) If Kantian thought is compatible with Marxism, then Kantian thought against Freedom of Press, Freedom of no being a slave, etc. (3) And yes the Democratic Party of the US, the German CDU are states.

Comment: @Felicia We aren't living in Capitalism, but in Hampered Capitalism to Soft Socialism

Comment: @ErdelvonMises "(3) And yes the Democratic Party of the US, the German CDU are states." Wow... that's utterly ridiculous.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises: Political parties aren't states. They often control states, but just as often - don't. That you are identifying both and doubling down on this identification, when almost all do not, shows a high level of intellectual vacuity and delusion which is not hidden by references to books or papers. And it also makes your suggestions that others provide 'citations' for their arguments both irritating and annoying because you are not adhering to either common-sense or rigorous academic argument.

Comment: @MoziburUllah If they control or no an Central State would no be relevant. What common-sense? the same that thing economic equality is just, when is just slavery and starvation?. And I am adhering to trivial logic coming form the definitions. What kind of Marxian Indoctrinator are you?

Comment: @Erdel von Mises: Your arguments are without substance and you are merely engaging in noxious polemics and personal attacks. I am not an 'indoctrinator', Marxist or otherwise. What's the point of talking about 'definitions' when you can't observe the simplest distinction between a party and a state? Your logic is trivial because it lacks both logic and common-sense.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Actually taking the definition of state in that manner, will make everything a state, because there is no social organization without political organization.

Comment: @Erdel von Mises: There you go again, I did not define a state. And one can argue witb your thesis 'there is no social orhanisation without political organisation'. For example, Oxfam is a social organisation, it is avowedly apolitical. The family is seen as the basic unit of social organisation, and whilst plenty of families are political, they are not thought of in this manner.

Comment: @MoziburUllah You did no defined state, but I did. If you check the definition that I gave all the political parties are also states [1] trivial conclusion for the definition. Thus it is following rigorous logical argument, and my response was the acknowledging of the problems of that position. And I think I got mistaken to take the definition of political science as the study of the structures of power, thus making everything political?

[1]: Note the main difference between the central states and other political organizations is that the central state is the monopoly of violence.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Thus I reaffirm that an state is a political organization as given by meridian-webster dictionary. Thus every political party is a state, but their differ of central state because they don't have the monopoly of violence.

Comment: @Erdel von mises: At this level of discussion definitions are spurious. It's clear to anyone with an iota of common sense that political parties are not the same as a state. This is just as true for one-party states. You're just throwing around simple political concepts without the simplest understanding of them.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Sorry that I don't think common sense is more valid than logic.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises: Common sense invented logic whereas logic, according to Hegel, comes 'limping' far behind reason.

Answer (score 1):

Ethics is preoccupied with judging actions and behaviors, not with economical systems. As such, even benign dictatorships with slavery can persist for some time with all actors behaving ethically given any ethical framework. And the most ideal and egalitarian economic system can exist with all actors doing horrible unethical things all day for years.

Even worse, the core of Kantian ethics is relative morality, allowing different people to reasonably disagree on any subject of morality based on their individual values. So asking a question about **objective** judgement in a subjective framework seems to miss the whole point.

Kant himself lived before a public debate on capitalism vs. socialism was a thing, so he could not comment on that.

So the question as phrased makes no sense.

And an analysis of economical models probably belongs to a different site than this one.

Comment: Ethics is inextricably tied to economic and political systems. Any kind of action that can cause harm or benefit - economic, political, military, private - may be moral or immoral. Most would say slavery is immoral. Some would say capitalism leads to immoral greed among the few to the detriment of the many. Others would say communism leads to immoral concentration of political power to the detriment of the many. Some would say taxation involves immoral theft, others would say taxation is a moral duty for the public benefit.

Comment: "linked". Sure. Anything can be linked to ethics. That does not mean any question is on topic for this site, just because it can be linked to ethics.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, socialism is not incomparable with capitalism. The position of [market socialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/socialism/#MarkSoci) can broadly be described as the belief that lasse faire capitalism is flawed and should be replaced with an alternative form of capitalism.

Second, as far as I know Kant wrote nothing on economics. The most prominent philosopher who applied Kantian ethics to economic thought was undoubtedly [John Rawls](https://iep.utm.edu/rawls/):

> John Rawls was arguably the most important political philosopher of
> the twentieth century... [Rawls] aims to build on Kant’s central ideas and to improve on them in certain respects.

Rawls himself [explicitly denied](https://giuseppecapograssi.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/rawls99.pdf) that he was a socialist of capitalist.

> The theory of justice does not by itself favor either form of regime
> [capitalism or socialism]. As we have seen, the decision as to which
> system is best for a given people depends upon their circumstances,
> institutions, and historical traditions.

It is noteworthy that both Rawls and Kant attempt to avoid an ethnocentrism using this tactic. However, other claim that Rawls' society could only be possible under [socialism](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23557707), while other claim the same thing about [capitalism](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/700108). Personally, I believe this results from different philosophers using different definitions of 'socialism' and less on what his ideal society would actually look like. As the SEP [notes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/socialism/):

> In his 1924 Dictionary of Socialism, Angelo Rappoport canvassed no
> fewer than forty definitions of socialism.

Comment: What happened with the Human Right of Private Property?, Clearly Socialism go against that Right, thus Justice only favors Capitalism.

Comment: Capitalism and Market are no the same. Capitalism is private ownership of the means of production, thus basically all the market socialism mentioned in the encyclopedia are no capitalism.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises Read Art 14 Abs. 2 GG (German constitution, human right to own property): The maxim "Property has its [social] responsibilities" is known since Cicero. The UN charta even explicitly mentions social ownership (ownership by groups). You appear increasingly delusional with your partisan use of terms.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking You mean the Charta of the International Mafia to the Expansion of Pure Socialism officially know as UN[1]?. Or the German government that  support systematic stealing thought Inflation (University of California Libraries, 1900) policies by the ECB, and does comply with the enforcement by treat of force of value over the FIAT currency called Euro (Thus inflicting human rights). PD1: I am sure a economist would no disagree with my use of the terms. PD2: What are that "social" responsibilities?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking  
[1]: Just the fact that  they thing that education is a human right and ignore the basic economic fact that minimal wage either create unemployment or just is plain impact-less is enough , because they support minimal wage. Is enough to prove they as the said. University of California Libraries. (1900). The American dictionary of the English language. New York: Collier. https://archive.org/details/americandiction00lyon

Comment: @ErdelvonMises I studied economics under professors who wouldn't know whether to laugh or cry reading this nonsense. You adhere to economics that are more than 100 years old? Fine. But don't expect to be taken any more seriously than a Freudian in contemporary psychology.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Are you referring to the use of the correct and historical definition of inflation?. Something that looks like they refer today as monetary base.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Literally of UN charta never mentions ownership by groups (https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/full-text), neither there is one mention of either ownership or property.

Comment: @ErdelvonMises I meant the UDHR, article 18. Thougjt that much would be clear if we talk about the human right to property.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Article 18 "everyone has the right to own property alone as well as in association with others", It does imply that common ownership of something is considered a right by the ONU,

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Sorry I get confused, but what It have do to here?